# Casting A Collection of Collections - C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, web

I have a function that returns `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<string>>`. I want to use this function, building on the basic `IEnumerable`, assigning it to a `List<List<string>>`. This would be easy if I just had one dimension (i.e. one collection), and would be solved by using the `ToList()` method - but how do i do this for an `IEnumerable<IEnumberable<string>>` without iterating through each of the items?

Comment: I think you have to iterate though all the items, IEnumerable only support iteration. It does depend on what the object is underneath! Some code?

Comment: I think you need to elaborate a bit more. what do you mean "if I just had one dimension"? also, you can't build a list of the items without iterating through them. how else would the list be generated? an IEnumerable is not necessarily "concrete"; that is, each item in the enumerable may not exist until you access it.

Comment: By 1 dimension I mean 1 dimension....As in 1 list. 2 dimensions is a list of lists..like 1d and 2d arrays....

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use [Enumerable.SelectMany](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany.aspx)

For example(from MSDN)

```
PetOwner[] petOwners = 
    { new PetOwner { Name="Higa, Sidney", 
          Pets = new List<string>{ "Scruffy", "Sam" } },
      new PetOwner { Name="Ashkenazi, Ronen", 
          Pets = new List<string>{ "Walker", "Sugar" } },
      new PetOwner { Name="Price, Vernette", 
          Pets = new List<string>{ "Scratches", "Diesel" } } };

// Query using SelectMany().
IEnumerable<string> query1 = petOwners.SelectMany(petOwner => petOwner.Pets);
```

Probably the best resource on this topic(J.Skeet):

[Reimplementing LINQ to Objects: Part 9 - SelectMany](https://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/12/27/reimplementing-linq-to-objects-part-9-selectmany.aspx)

Here's another example with a `List<List<string>>` like in your question:

```
var lists = new List<List<string>>();
lists.Add(new List<String>(new[] { "A", "B", "C" }));
lists.Add(new List<String>(new[] { "D", "E", "F", "G" }));
lists.Add(new List<String>(new[] { "H", "I", "J", "K", "L" }));
var all = lists.SelectMany(i => i);
String allLetters= String.Format("All letters: {0}",String.Join(",",all));
```

Answer (score 1):

I 'm assuming you have some kind of `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>>`. You can flatten it using something like this: `YourList.SelectMany(x => x)`.